# Getting the average of a Subquery SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have the following code where i am trying to get the aircraft ids (aircraftid) and the number of times they have been serviced (count(serviceid)) but only show them if the count(serviceid) is more than the average number of count(serviceid).

```
select aircraftid, s.times
from(
select aircraftid, count(serviceid) as times
from service
group by aircraftid
) as s
having times > avg(times);
```

but when i run this it returns no rows

when i change the code to

```
select aircraftid, s.times
from(
select aircraftid, count(serviceid) as times
from service
group by aircraftid
) as s
having times > 2;
```

it returns rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this-

```
SELECT aircraftid, 
COUNT(serviceid) AS times
FROM service
GROUP BY aircraftid
HAVING COUNT(serviceid) > (
    SELECT AVG(T) FROM 
    (
        SELECT count(serviceid) T
        FROM service
        GROUP BY aircraftid
    )A
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  a cross join on a subquery for avg

```
  select aircraftid, s.times
  from(
    select aircraftid, count(serviceid) as times
    from service
    group by aircraftid
  ) as s
  cross join (
    select avg(times) avg_time
    from (
      select aircraftid, count(serviceid) as times
      from service
      group by aircraftid
    ) t
  ) t2 
  where s.times > t2.avg_time
```

or the use a subquer in having clause because  you need aircraftid column in select   but this is not in group by  ..and yoy need  the overall avg..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select aircraftid, s.times
from (select aircraftid, count(*) as times,
             avg(count(*)) over () as avg_times
      from service
      group by aircraftid
     ) s
where times > avg_times;
```

Window functions were introduced in MySQL 8 and are the best way to solve this problem.